# R sampling distribution shapiro.test

Tags: r, testing, distribution

I was trying to simulate the sample distribution of the sample mean in R

```
rm(list = ls())
install.packages("fGarch")
library(fGarch)
library(tidyverse)
#create sekewed distribution
N <- 10000
x <- rnbinom(N, 5, .5)
mean(x)
df <- data.frame(x=x)
df %>% ggplot(aes(x=x)) + geom_histogram()

#distribution of the sample mean
r <- replicate(1000, {
  mean(sample(x, 10, replace = TRUE))
})
mean(r)
dfr <- data.frame(r=r)
dfr %>% ggplot(aes(x=r)) + geom_histogram()
shapiro.test(r)
```

To my astonishment shapiro test produces very low p values, although the sampling distribution looks aprox norm distributed. For lower numbers of replication the p values increase. This is the opposite of what I expected.
What is my mistake????

Thanks,

Hans

Comment: number `10` in `sample` is small. Increase that number.

Comment: Take a look at the second paragraph in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test#Interpretation
As for the increasing *p* value, decreasing the number of samples will decrease the sensitivity of the test (the *p* value will decrease as you add more samples from the same non-normal distribution).